# PackageReference doesn't reference library

Tags: msbuild, nuget, packagereference

When I try to add a package reference to the .csproj file I am having the problem that the actual DLL is not referenced in the project. My example is:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json">
        <Version>11.0.2</Version>
    </PackageReference>
</ItemGroup>
```

The package [appears in the Nuget package manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/byJ7b.png) but not in the project's "References" list and the assembly cannot be accessed from the project.

I am using Visual Studio 15.7.4

Thanks

Comment: are there build errors? does that package reference show any warnings? (warning list in error list window, warning icon)